# Oultook 2013 InlineResponse - Disable Forward button

Tags: c#, outlook

I have a Form Server running in Outlook and I specify a different MessageClass (say IPM.Note.Test) for items which are to be handled by my form server. If you select an item, with MessageClass IPM.Note.Test, in the explorer view, and try to Forward from ribbon button, I prevent the user from doing so, by hooking into Forward command.

In OL 2013, if you have reading pane visible, and select an item in Explorer, you can see its preview and can Forward/Reply/ReplyAll from toolbar at the top of the reading-pane, which would create an InlineResponse.

I want to hook into this Forward action, and prevent the user from doing so, as I do for the Explorer-Ribbon Forward command.

I am aware of the Explorer.InlineResponse event which is fired on any action which creates an Inline Response, but this event is fired after the action, not before it, and it fires for Reply, ReplyAll and Forward, all three of them. I only want to intercept Forward. There is no information in the event to tell which action triggered it.

Is there a way to identify the the action which triggered the event, before the InlineResponse is created?

Or is there a way to stop the InlineResponse from being created? (From code, as I know you can disable it in OL options).

Or is there a way to disable these actions/inline response from Explorer.SelectionChange event?

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for taking time to answer this.

Something else came up and I put this issue on hold for a bit.

As I mentioned earlier, I have my own Form Server with a different MessageClass. So the MailItem object I get in ExplorerSelectionChange event, is not a *pure* Outlook MailItem, its rather *my* MailItem and unfortunately, at the moment, its unable to get Actions property on it, probably because my Form Server implementation doesnt return a proper one.

So, although, for a normal MailItem, Enabled property will work, it doesnt solve my problem ... :(

I x-posted to Outlook Dev Forum as well, and someone suggested the following:

```
Private Sub myOlExp_InlineResponse(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim a As MailItem
Set a = Item
If a.To = "" Then
    a.Close olDiscard ‘close the mail item
    MsgBox "Forward is not supported"
End If
End Sub
```

Although a bit hacky, and not a great user-experience, but I'm taking this for an answer for the moment, as it works.

Shared here, in case someone else comes looking for it.

[Complete thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/dd1ab22d-d8a4-41bf-be6a-8b776d019e00/oultook-2013-inlineresponse-disable-forward-button?forum=outlookdev)

Answer (score 0):

`MailItem` object exposes the `Actions` collection. Retrieve the Forward action, set the `Action.Enabled` property to true, call `MailItem.Save`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [Enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.action.enabled.aspx) property of the corresponding Action object instance to **false**. `True` if the action is enabled in the application and `false` - if the action is disabled.